# Save HTMLDocument

Tags: java, swing, dom, htmleditorkit

```
package htmldocsave;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;

import java.io.*;

public class HTMLDocSave 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HTMLDocument doc = new HTMLDocument();
        HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();

        File f = new File("greeting.html");

        try 
        {
            kit.insertHTML(doc,doc.getLength(),"<b>Hello</b>",0,0,null);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);

            ???????????????????????????
                    fos.close();
        } 
        catch (BadLocationException | IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

How to save a HTML document on the file system? The javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument class doesn't override the `toString()` method and `getText()` removes tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `HTMLEditorKit.write()` method.

Comment: Just to point out that HTMLEditorKit's write() has a glitch whereby the last empty paragraph in the document is removed. Fortunately, Stanislav published a fix here: http://java-sl.com/tip_html_kit_last_empty_par.html. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

That's all what I exactly needed:
`kit.write(fos, doc, 0, doc.getLength());`

Answer (score 1):

I guess this post is very similar to your question:[Get String from HTMLDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472049/get-all-html-as-a-string-from-htmldocument)

Then write the String to a File. There are many different methods to do this. Take a look at [Write String to File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java).